# if $f(z) = e^z$ and $C$ is any curve joining $ -i\pi/2$ and $i\pi/2 $ find $ \int_C f(z)dz $

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

> If $f(z) =  e^z$ and $C$ is any curve joining $-i\pi/2 $ and $i\pi/2 $ find $$\int_C f(z)dz.$$

So $e^{z} = e^{x}e^{iy}$ and $z=z(y)$ then $z(a) = -i\pi/2$ and $z(b) = i\pi/2$.
Then $$\int_C f(z)dz = \int_a^b f(z) z'(y) dy $$ and then I got stuck can't integral an unknown function.

How do I proceed?
thanks

Comment: You can replace $C$ by a curve of your liking, since $e^z$ is holomorphic.

Comment: You are given $f(z)=e^z$ why is it unknown?

Answer (score 0):

Proceeding by brute force, suppose we parameterize the curve $C$ as $z=z(t)$ where $z(t_1)=-i\pi/2$ and $z(t_2)=i\pi/2$.  Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_C e^z\,dz&=\int_{t_1}^{t_2}e^{x(t)}(\cos(y(t))+i\sin(y(t)))\left(\frac{dx (t)}{dt}+i\frac{d y(t)}{dt}\right)\,dt\\\\
&=\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{x(t)}\cos(y(t))\right)\,dt+i\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{x(t)}\sin(y(t))\right)\,dt\\\\
&=\left.e^{z(t)}\right|_{t=t_1}^{t=t_2}\\\\
&=e^{z(t_2)}-e^{z(t_1)}\\\\
&=e^{i\pi/2}-e^{-i\pi/2}\\\\
&=2i\sin(\pi/2)\\\\
&=2i
\end{align}$$

---

**NOTE:**

Alternatively, we can exploit a [consequence of Cauchy's Integral Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem#Discussion) and write immediately

$$\int_C e^z\,dz=e^{z_2}-e^{z_1}=2i$$

for any path $C$ that connects $z_1=-i\pi/2$ to $z_2=i\pi/2$.

Comment: Nestro, please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  -Mark